# Adding Windows ADUC SG to Sudoers

Tags: sudo, amazon-linux

On an AWS Workspace utilizing Amazon Linux 2 (Red hat underneath), I am attempting to add a Windows Active Directory Security Group to the Sudoers file and am having some terrible luck in getting it to recognize my user in the group as a sudoer.

At this current time, I have tried adding the group to the bottom of the file as three different entries, all to no avail:

```
%DOMAIN\SG\ -\ IT\ -\ Help\ Desk ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%SG\ -\ IT\ -\ Help\ Desk ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%SG\ -\ IT\ -\ Help\ Desk@DOMAIN.COM ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

(Unfortunately, the group is so widely used and locked down that there is no option at all to rename it so it doesn't include spaces.)

No matter the three options I choose to use up above, if I SSH into the Linux box and attempt to do, for example, sudo su (just to test access), it just says that my user account is not part of the sudoers file.

If I type "id" into the SSH window, it does show that my user account I SSH'd into the box with is part of the SG I put into the sudoers file.

Is there anything I am missing that will allow me to add an SG to these boxes for sudo access?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add AD users to sudo group not working | CentOS 6.7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257871/add-ad-users-to-sudo-group-not-working-centos-6-7)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like no. Using the double quotes option just gave me a syntax error in the file. Using the \x20 option, so it's SG\x20-\x20IT\x20Help\x20Desk ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL gives the exact same result, not found in the sudoers file.

Comment: I figured it out. Evidently in the sudoers file, you need to do it like this: %DOMAIN\\SG\ -\.....

Each \ is probably just saying treat me as a space or whatever, so that very first DOMAIN\SG.... was doing a DOMAIN SG, not DOMAIN\SG like I thought.

Comment: Strange. You should have been able to use `%"SG - IT - Help Desk" ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: Yeah for whatever reason, that seemed like a no-go. Every iteration I tried just gave me a syntax error in the sudoers file every time I tried to do something.

Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: Try this - seems to work for me, `%SG\x20-\x20IT\x20-\x20Help\x20Desk ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. If that is syntactically valid but doesn't give users access, you'll need to identify exactly how you're bringing in the AD groups (Samba, `sssd`, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Evidently in the sudoers file, you need to do it like this: %DOMAIN\SG\ -..... Each \ is probably just saying treat me as a space or whatever, so that very first DOMAIN\SG.... was doing a DOMAIN SG, not DOMAIN\SG like I thought.